# Equality of two random variables

Tags: random-variable, convergence

Following excerpt is from the fifth chapter of ["All of statistics" by Wasserman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387402721):

> Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ is a sequence of random variables which
>   are independent and suppose each has a $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ distribution. Since these all have the same distribution, we are tempted to say that $X_n$ ``converges'' to $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. But this can’t quite be right since $P(X_n = X) = 0$ for all $n$. (Two continuous random variables are equal with probability zero.)

I have two questions here:

1. What does it mean to say $X_n = X$ when these are random variables?
2. Why the probability $P(X_n = X)$ is $0$ even when they have exactly same distribution?

Comment: Consider you have two fair six sided dice numbered 1 to 6 (one red and one green). If you roll them the outcomes have the same distribution, but if the probability that they're equal is 1/6. Now imagine you rolled a 60 sided die of each colour. These results also have the same distribution but the probability they they're equal is only 1/60. Now imagine you have two independent continuous uniformly distributed values (clearly they have the same distribution). Now consider the distribution of their difference, D (it's symmetric triangular). What's P(D=0)?

Comment: @Glen_b: Right! I understand what you mean. But the author does not say explicitly what he means by two random variables being equal.

Comment: Why would he need to beyond writing $X_n=X$? How is $X_n=X$ ambiguous?

Comment: Because he doesn't define what the equality means for random variables. For example, suppose I say that two vector spaces V1 and V2 are equal. Isn't it ambiguous unless I define what I mean by their equality?

Answer (score 2):

The random variables $X_n$ and $X$ are both functions from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ to the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Take, e.g., $\Omega=[0,1]$. The event $X_n=X$ is thus the set$$\mathfrak{E}=\{\omega\in\Omega;\ X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\}$$The $X_i$'s being [independent](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/) from the limit $X$ (in a probabilistic sense), and continuous, the probability measure of the above set is zero. Indeed, by the definition of independence, the measure of a product set $A\times B$ is then $\mathbb{P}(A)\times\mathbb{P}(B)$, meaning that the product measure of $(X_,X)$ is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and implying that a measure zero set like $\mathfrak{E}$ has probability zero to occur$$\mathbb{P}(\mathfrak{E})=0$$

Comment: I don't understand this argument. Saying that probability measure of the above set is 0 simply shifts the origin of the question. The question is: "Why".